# Can you install GeoFire using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, geofire

There seems to be a podspec for GeoFire: at https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/blob/master/GeoFire.podspec, but CocoaPods has no idea it exists http://cocoapods.org/?q=geofire. Is there a way to install GeoFire with CocoaPods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like GeoFire has created a podspec, but hasn't published it on CocoaPods. This should work though:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git', :tag => 'v1.1.0'
```

Disclaimer: I have never used GeoFire or don't even know what it does. The solution is provided solely based on the information in the question.

Comment: Hmm seems it's not quite set up yet, the 1.0.0 tagged in git doesn't have the podspec. 1.1.0 does, but the pod still lists the version as 1.0. Seems to work through.

Comment: @astromme Edited as per your comment!